# Is there an API in JSX to ignore if self closing tags like <br> is not closed?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am creating a simple ReactJS component using JSX as below.

```
<script type="text/jsx">
        var HelloWorld = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (

                    <div class="ui left icon input">
                        <input placeholder="Search users..." type="text" />
                          <i class="users icon"></i>
                    </div>

                    );
            }
        });
        React.render(<HelloWorld />, document.body);
    </script>
```

The above code works fine if I close the input tag `<input placeholder="Search users..." type="text" />`.
If I don't close the tag `<input placeholder="Search users..." type="text">` the JSX throws this error and the React/JSX component is not rendered:
[image: FireBug Error]

I have some legacy code where tags like `<input >`, `<br>` are not closed. As per W3C, it is also not mandatory to close these tags. 
I want to move this code to React components using the JSX. However I want JSX to ignore if self closing/void tags are not closed.

> Is there an api or way to configure JSX to igonre this?

Comment: JSX requires all tags to be closed, it creates new tags that have nothing to do with the W3C which still require that it be closed, whether it's a component tag or a br tag, why not just close them?

Comment: This just means JSX is just a parser, it is not smart enough to detect the type of tags.

Comment: Why not using some transformation using regex as a way of refactoring. If JSX is expecting a specific language to generate modifications on the dom  and the parser has been tested for this language than we shouldn't be changing the language or the parser.

Comment: Why would you expect (or want) JSX to behave like HTML? They are not the same thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must close all JSX tags. JSX is transpiled into function calls, not compiled into HTML. You can think about it more like XHTML if it helps.